# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'USA' django

Tags: django

Good day.

Am having a model called AddInv

```
AddInv(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sold = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    details = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Signup, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country
```

Model for Signup is

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField( null=True)
    zipcode = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length = 75, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 75, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 75, null= True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 32, null=True, choices = CATEGORIES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country
```

and a views to filter by country

```
def homepage(request):    # Client View
    context = {}
    items = get_object_or_404(AddInv, country="USA")
    print "Items", items
    return render(request, "selly/homepage.html", {'items': items})
```

Am having  error pointing to

```
items = get_object_or_404(AddInv, country="USA")
```

What could be wrong with the code

Comment: Parameter `country` must be an instance of `Signup` model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Just an assume

```
items = get_object_or_404(AddInv, country__country="USA")
```

Comment: Thanks @itzmeoontv for you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
items = AddInv.objects.filter(country__country="USA")
```

which worked